# How do I get channel information in a Mirth Connect JavaScript Reader Source Connector?

Tags: javascript, mirth

I'm working with Mirth Connect Server 3.8.1 and I'm using a JavaScript Reader as a channel's Source Connector. I'm trying to get the current channel id, but it seems that that's not possible. After googling I've tried the following things to see if yielded any results but it did not:

```
logger.info(typeof channelId != 'undefined' ? ChannelUtil.getDeployedChannelName(channelId) : 'N/A');
logger.info(typeof connector != 'undefined' ? connector : 'N/A');
logger.info(typeof channel != 'undefined' ? channel : 'N/A');
```

This just produces three "N/A" in the logs. Obviously I could hard-code the channel id, but I want to export this config eventually and be able to import it to other environments without needing to edit anything. Plus it feels like a Source Connector piece of JS should know who it is working for.

How do I get this information from within the script?

**Update:** The answer "This should work" is essentially correct, because as it turns out this does work in a brand new channel. The channel I was working with was imported and although I could find no other scripts affecting that channel, it was clearly broken. So possible the real answer is "Mirth Connect Server 3.8.1 has a bug that causes this to sometimes not work and the workaround is creating a new channel."

**Update 2:** The culprit turned out to be me using the `channelId` variable in a local scope later, something along the lines of:

```
for (var i=0; i<allChannelIds.size(); i++) {
    var channelId = allChannelIds.get(i);
    // Other code
}
```

I wrote that before realizing there was a global scope `channelId` variable and before needing it. Apparently this resets it to `undefined`. If the global `channelId` was set each time the script executes, this should not be a problem, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: I would expect `channelId` to work. The answer by @Neils shows this working in an older mirth version, but I have no reason to believe that has changed. `connector` would not be defined in a Javascript Reader context, and I'm not aware of `channel` being defined in any context.

Possibly you have other code that is causing your issue? If you try it in a brand new channel where it is the only code in the Javascript Reader do you get the same result? Are there any code templates assigned to this channel that could be creating a conflict?

Comment: @agermano I tried what you suggested and created a completely new channel and after copy pasting Neils line below in the Source JavaScript Reader it worked like a charm. Pasting the same line into the original Source JavaScript Reader still caused printing of 'undefined'. So something must be wrong with that channel instead. That channel is very plain, I'm not finding any other scripts that could be causing this issue. The only difference with that channel is that it was exported/imported from another environment. In any case there's a workaround now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overcomplicating things.

In Mirth 3.5.1 the following code worked fine for me in the Transformer on the source connector of a channel:

```
logger.info("Channel ID: "+channelId);
```

The result was something like this:

```
[2020-02-25 13:03:30,033]  INFO  (transformer:?): Channel ID: 1122e1c7-34af-4141-9388-533005346d0b
```

This ID matches the ID that appears in the Mirth dashboard and on the channel summary page.

I also verified that the code worked in a Javascript Reader.  In this case, the logged message was

```
[2020-02-25 14:33:20,004]  INFO  (js-connector:?): Channel ID: 1122e1c7-34af-4141-9388-533005346d0b
```

Comment: OP specifically said in a Javascript Reader, which I would expect to still work, but I haven't tested it myself yet. The first line of the example code uses the same variable that you did, and according to the original post, that variable was undefined.

Comment: @agermano, I just tested my code in a Javascript Reader.  It worked, though the logged message was slightly different.  I am using an older version of Mirth than the OP mentioned.  Think that's the source of the problem?

Comment: This answer is correct as it _should_ work. If you came to this page because this didn't work for you, try it in a brand new channel first.

Answer (score 0):

To get Channel Name you can use this code:

```js
var channelName = Packages.com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.ChannelController.getInstance().getDeployedChannelById(channelId).getName();
```